# cmake property VS_USER_PROPS silently ignored

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I try to add several existing props files (property-files come with gstreamer and I'd like to reuse them for Windows-builds instead of adding all dependencies by hand) to a project generated by cmake for Visual Studio 2019.

I've created one user.props file for this:

videolib.deps.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\share\vs\2010\libs\glib-2.0.props" />
    <Import Project="C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\share\vs\2010\libs\gstreamer-1.0.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

I don't get any errors, but the file is not added into the generated project.

Here are my CMakeLists.txt:

Root dir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE 1)
project(videolib
                VERSION 0.1
                DESCRIPTION "A videoplayer library based on a gstreamer. Allows playback and simple editing of a video."
                LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20 CACHE STRING "The C++ standard to use")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME)
    include(CTest)
endif()

add_subdirectory(videolib)
#add_subdirectory(test-videolib)
#add_subdirectory(test-videolib-impl)
```

In `videolib` subdir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

add_library(videolib-common INTERFACE)
target_sources(videolib-common INTERFACE
    src/videolib_impl.cpp
    src/videolib.cpp)
target_include_directories(videolib-common INTERFACE
    src
    include)

add_library(videolib SHARED)
target_link_libraries(videolib videolib-common)
set_target_properties(videolib PROPERTIES VS_USER_PROPS "videolib.deps.props")
```

No errors during configure:

```
(env) d:\projects\videolib\build>cmake -S .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/projects/videolib/build
```

But during build (`cmake --build --config Debug .`) I get an error that `glib.h` is not found, which is typical when gstreamer dependencies are not added. Also `videolib.deps.props` is not mentioned anyway in generated project files.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks, adding `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/` does fix the issue. If you add your response as an answer I'll mark it as `accepted` answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
set_property(
  TARGET videolib
  PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/videolib.deps.props"
)
```

Likely it is just searching in the wrong directory.

Comment: The path in `VS_USER_PROPS` just gets inserted verbatim into the VS project file. So an absolute path of some form or another should always be used. (Note that this behavior allows you to reference msbuild variables like `$(UserRootDir)` and `$(Platform)`).